# Animate opacity messes up my text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create following effect: when I **hover** over my link, that link changes color, this part work's but problem with my code is that i cannot see my text when i hover over.  I know that i can solve this by adding images to my span and anchor tag and I also know that there is a plugin that animates color, but ***IF POSSIBLE*** i would like to solve this ***WITHOUT*** background images and plugins. Is that possible?  
I created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kyWth/3/) for you to see my problem.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').hover(function () {
        var heightCheck = $(this).outerHeight();
        //alert(heightCheck);
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000);
        $('.yellow').height(heightCheck);
        $('.yellow').css({
            'margin-top': -heightCheck
        });
    }, function (heightCheck) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000, function () {
            $('.yellow').css({
                'margin-top': +heightCheck
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're already using jQuery, why not use jQuery UI (the plugin you reference) and do everything with one element.

Think about it, are you going to remember to include that extra `.yellow` span every time you want a link like that?

Also, why not use progressive enhancement and do this all with CSS? You could even do a jQuery fallback for IE?

See my attached Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/nzcGy/3/

Comment: +1 but even better than doing a check for ie would be to use modernizr and check for [css animations](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css)

Comment: The advantage with this method, is for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox - you don't have to use any javascript at all! And we only have to use js for pesky IE.

Comment: Agreed, but I thought that might be getting a little ahead of ourselves :)

Comment: That is the effect i was looking for! +1 by me!!

Comment: I would definitely use the `addClass` animating ability that jquery ui has, rather than animating inline style. If I used jquery ui, that is.

Comment: actually, it turns out that jquery ui's addClass method does not blend colors. (at least not in IE).. the method in my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve here, this looks like it would be solved with one line of CSS. e.g...

```
.link:hover { background-color: yellow;}
```

The reason you can't see your text is cause opacity: 0 renders it invisible.

Comment: Thx for answer!! Didnt work:( I know that opacity is the problem but don't know how to achieve that my text shows:(

Answer (score 1):

Change it so that the grey background color is applied to the li style and not the link itself. Take off the animate opacity line for .link as well.

Maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5bXHW/

Comment: Txh for answer but look's like I will have to use jquery UI!

Answer (score 1):

I played around with opacity to get this result, looks much better now http://jsfiddle.net/kyWth/37/ link's opacity and span opacity is both set to 0.5 now. Is it any near to what you want?

**UPDATE** Made changes to your code here http://jsfiddle.net/kyWth/39/ , works perfect, you don't need the span either.